# Pipelining in a polynomial

Tags: verilog, pipelining

Please suggest me some methods where I can implement pipelining to implement a 6th order  polynomial.

My ideas :
Perform three additions concurrently ie:

```
aox^0 + a1x^1 = sa10;
a2x^2 + a3x^3 = sa32;
a4x^4 + a5x^5 = sa54;
```

Also store the values of `sa10`,`sa32` in flipflop1.

Next add `sa10 + sa32 = sa3210` store it in flipflop2, also store `sa54` in flipflop2

Next add `sa3210 + sa54` to get the result.

Any thoughts about the above logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest, first try to do this without pipelining, in one clock cycle, and then break it into multiple stage.

The design depends on several factors:

- How much resources you want to allocate (affects area/power)
- What is your clock cycle time? Since multipliers are slow and expensive, you don't want to connect many of them back o back.
- What is your throughput? Do you want a result per clock cycle, or a result per N number of clock cycles (this way you can do resource sharing).

Here is an example:
Lets assume you can tolerate the delay of only two consecutive multipliers per clock cycle, and you want a throughput of one polynomial per clock cycle. Your pipeline structure can be like this:

**stage 1:** inputs: {a5,...,a0,x}

```
Combination circuit:

{a5,...,a0,x}---------------------->{a5,...,a0,x}
                        |-->------->x^2
            x->[mult]->x^2->[mult]->x^3
```

**stage 2:** inputs: {a5,...,a0,x,x^2,x^3}

```
Combination circuit:
{a5,...,a0,x,x^2,x^3}------------------------>{a5,...,a0,x,x^2,x^3}
                                  |-->------->x^4
                    x^3->[mult]->x^4->[mult]->x^5
```

**stage 3:** inputs: {a5,...,a0,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5}

```
Combination circuit:
(a0,x^0)->[mult]->a0x^0--\      
(a1,x^1)->[mult]->a1x^1--\ 
(a2,x^2)->[mult]->a2x^2-->[sum]-> a0x^0+a1x^1+...+a5x^5      
(a3,x^3)->[mult]->a3x^3--/      
(a4,x^4)->[mult]->a4x^4--/      
(a5,x^5)->[mult]->a5x^5--/
```

Notice that we are using a lot of resources (multipliers) in order to achieve one result per cycle throughput.

If you can't have more than one multiplier per stage, you need to break stages 1 and 2 into two stages each.